# Need a match expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the following

```
/// <reference path="../defs/node/node.d.ts"/>
```

to

Basically the string between `/// <reference path="` and `"/>` any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using capturing group:

```
>'/// <reference path="../defs/node/node.d.ts"/>'.match(/\/\/\/ <reference path="(.*?)"\/>/)[1]
"../defs/node/node.d.ts"
```

Comment: what about the `///` part ?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

`var g='/// <reference path="../defs/node/node.d.ts"/>'.match(/\/\/\/ <reference path=\"(.*?)\"\/>/i)`

which yields

`["/// <reference path="../defs/node/node.d.ts"/>", "../defs/node/node.d.ts"]`

so we want`g[1]`

`"../defs/node/node.d.ts"`

Comment: @BASarat well no , the asnwer doesnt treat `///`